# Is there a PHP class for performing most common functions with a MS SQL database?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Before I go starting to write the functions to connect to, retrieve the rows from my MS SQL database, I was wondering if there is already a publicly available class that wraps this functionality into a class object.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: You actually probably want to be directed toward PDO as opposed the answer you accepted Devcoder.

Comment: @Anther - Can you please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?
[SQL PHP Class](http://mogames.com.br/class_sql.txt)

Comment: Yes that's along the lines of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. You can just use PHP's [PDO classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).There is a PDO [driver available for MS SQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) server.